# converting map to object give me null properties object

Tags: json, flutter

this is the code that Retrofit built for me and I made some changes to it.

_result is a Response<Map<String, dynamic>> that fetched with dio.fetch()

```
    List<ArticleModel> value = _result.data!['articles']
        .map<ArticleModel>(
            (dynamic i) => ArticleModel.fromJson(i as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
```

and below is the fromJson ArticleModel constructor

```
class ArticleModel extends ArticleEntity {
  const ArticleModel({
    int? id,
    String? author,
    String? title,
    String? description,
    String? url,
    String? urlToImage,
    String? publishedAt,
    String? content,
  });


  factory ArticleModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ArticleModel(
      author: map['author'] ?? '',
      title: map['title'] ?? '',
      description: map['description'] ?? '',
      url: map['url'] ?? '',
      urlToImage: map['urlToImage'] ?? '',
      publishedAt: map['publishedAt'] ?? '',
      content: map['content'] ?? '',
    );
  }
}
```

I added some logs to it but the second log gave me an object with a null property

```
    log(_result.data!['articles'][0]['title'], name: 'title'); -> gives me correct title string


    List<ArticleModel> value = _result.data!['articles']
        .map<ArticleModel>(
            (dynamic i) => ArticleModel.fromJson(i as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();

    log(value[0].toString(), name: 'articleModel'); -> gives me ArticleModel(null, null, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this

```
class ArticleModel extends ArticleEntity {
  const ArticleModel({
    id,
    author,
    title,
    description,
    url,
    urlToImage,
    publishedAt,
    content,
  }) : super(
          id: id,
          author: author,
          title: title,
          description: description,
          url: url,
          urlToImage: urlToImage,
          publishedAt: publishedAt,
          content: content,
        );
```

thanks to
[dragonfly02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455929/how-to-implement-inheritance-in-dart)